# Will static variables have different values for each client?

Tags: c#

I have created a Windows application (C#) in which some information is stored from the login form as a static variable - e.g user name and role of user is stored in static variables.

This application will run on LAN server and can be accessed by thin clients and at the same time multiple users will use this application.

I need to confirm that in this case can static variables act like session variables, as in web base system? Or are these static variables mixed together?

e.g User A and User B are logged in. Can User A information be mixed with User B information, if both are accessing the same application at same time but from different systems?

Comment: Did you do any research at all? Do you know what an AppDomain is? What is "same application"? Are they accessing the same instance of the same application?

Comment: This is the kind of thing you could test in less than 30 seconds.

Comment: yeah they are accessing same instance . and i didn't do any research for this yet and i don't have any idea about appdomain.

Comment: Are you sure all clients access the same process?

Answer (score 4):

Static fields are associated with the [AppDomain](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). According to the MSDN documentation, an AppDomain is:

> [...] an isolated environment where applications execute.

- If a process explicitly has multiple AppDomains associated with it, static fields will have multiple values. Each AppDomain will have its own set of values for the static fields.
- If a process only has one AppDomain, then the static fields are effectively globals with one value at any given time.

---

In any case, I don't think you should mess with AppDomains at all. In fact, you should just avoid static fields for this scenario altogether.

Instead, use a custom Session object that will store individual information for individual users. Create an instance of Session when a user starts a session and dispose/release it when the session ends. Make sure you don't mix two Session instances that belong to different users and you're good to go.

Comment: will you kindly explain AppDomain for me.?

Comment: but sessions are not functioning in windows app , these are only for web applications. am i right?

Comment: @Waqas I might be misunderstanding your problem, but I don't think you're right. The concept of a "session" exists in your use cases (since users can log in, do stuff and log out). Since the concept of a session already exists in your use cases, then modeling it in your code (by creating a Session class) is reasonable. Of course, all of this involves a bit of guessing, since we don't know what exactly you've used to write the server (WinForms? WPF? ASP.NET WebForms? ASP.NET MVC? Something else?).

Comment: @Waqas Then what I wrote is applicable for your case, especially the last paragraph. Avoid AppDomains and avoid static variables. Use a class (you can call it Session or anything else) and use non-static variables in it.

Answer (score 0):

There will only be 1 static variable.

If you have an object representing a client connection; and it's a static field of that class, it should be made into a instance field is toy need each client to have its own version; otherwise they will all share it.